# Word comprising Satisfaction and Relief

Tags: single-word-requests

When I finished cleaning out my late father's apartment, I felt relief at having finished an irksome task, but also satisfaction at having done it well. Is there a word that connotes both feelings?

Sample: "While I didn't relish cleaning out my late father's apartment, and had postponed the job several times, after I finally did it, I felt both relieved that is was over and proud that I had done a good job; in a word, I felt *RequestedWord*."

Comment: a sense of accomplishment

Comment: I would say "foley catheter", but I suppose most people would not understand that.

Comment: @HotLicks - I sure don't.

Comment: @HotLicks Relief yes, sense of accomplishment not so much

Answer (score 1):

No language is rich enough to have words for every exact nuance we which to express (which is why we can resort to devices such as using two words or a periphrase).

When faced with this question, we can turn to the traditional tool (a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/deliverance)) and poke around. Or (for those who speak two or more languages), get the word or phrase in another language and find how it has been translated into English.

For your case, I found (closer to the idea of relief):

> deliverance
>
> liberation
>
> riddance

Or, more with the idea of satisfaction:

> gratification

"Gratification" ("gratified") has the advantage that it conveys the idea of getting some satisfaction after doing something.

But:

> I felt satisfied *and* relieved.

would perhaps work even better, if that is what you want to say!

Comment: I think 'liberated' is better than 'liberation' after 'I felt', but otherwise I think that's a solid suggestion.